# Cannot find name 'require' - Angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, image, node-modules

Cannot compile after using fast-image-size node module. I tried serveral steps to slove this but nothis helped. Finally I add `"types": ["ts-node"],` to tsconfig.js file , but not helped. How do I solve this??
My typescript version is 3.7.3  .

[image: How this error display]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can
`declare var require: any`

Also instead of `var fast_image_size = require('../index.js')` you could try the following:

```
import fast_image_size from '../index.js' // or
import fast_image_size = require('../index.js')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're receiving this error because this is not how TypeScript handles file imports. TypeScript handles importing or including files in a slightly different manner. To resolve this:

-Remove line 198 ("var fast_image_size = require("..index.js");")

-Instead, at the top of the file add the following line:

```
import * as fast_image_size from '..index.js'
```

The rest of your script should then compile.